# Why is Eclipse trying to use JUnit5 when it should use JUnit4?

Tags: eclipse, junit4, junit5

I'm just going through a tutorial which is a Maven project in Eclipse, and it should run some tests using JUnit4, so I have put this dependency in the POM:

```
<dependency>    
  <groupId>junit</groupId>      
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>    
  <version>4.13</version>       
  <scope>test</scope> 
</dependency>
```

Still, trying to run the tests I get the following:
No tests found with testrunner 'JUnit5'

Why is Eclipse not using JUnit4 when this is the only dependency given in the project?

Comment: If you run `mvn test` on your command line, are the JUnit 4 test executed?

Comment: I tried this, and got a build success and a lot of "downloading this and that" messages, but it didn't really say that any test were executed, as far as I could see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **in** the **run configuration** you have chosen ***JUnit 4* as *Test Runner***, Eclipse uses JUnit 4 instead of JUnit 5 to run this test.

Please note that even though Eclipse preselects the matching Test Runner for new run configurations, it does not change the Test Runner for existing run configurations.

Comment: Thanks - yes it may well be a run configuration issue. But then, do you even have a tip about how to change this? I'm quite new in this area! (And also note that the problem is the opposite of what you suggest, I want to run with JUnit 4 and not 5.)

Comment: In _Run > Run Configurations..._ for a _JUnit_ test, you can choose the _Test runner_ in the _Test_ tab (which is the first tab).